# Can I have certain mods only in certain worlds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Let's say I have two Minecraft worlds and 20 mods. Can I make not enough items work with both the worlds but the other mods only work in the other world?

Comment: most people just use 2 launch profiles

Answer (score 2):

#### Not without multiple launch profiles.

Mods are loaded when the game starts, not when the world loads. As such, it is not possible to load different mods for different worlds.

You can make two profiles in the Minecraft Launcher, with different mods loaded into the different `minecraft.jar` (located in a subfolder of `.minecraft/versions`). But you will have to shut down Minecraft to switch worlds.